# Second clock on Ubuntu classic desktop

Tags: 22.04, clock

I'm using classic desktop session on Ubuntu and cannot figure out how to enable the second clock for other timezone on the top right corner. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I guess you're using GNOME.

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```

You can configure as much clock with different time zones.
Then you can view it in the notification panel.

And if you want to view it in top bar, you can use the extension called [Panel World Clock (Lite)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/). Now you can have multiple clocks at the same time in the top panel.

Comment: when I open the link of the panel world clock, it shows "Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running". What does that mean?

Comment: @kstn I think you need to explain what a "classic desktop session" is. What desktop are you running? Is it Unity?

Comment: @kstn what desktop environment are you using ?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Conman17 it is gnome-session-flashback